# Python error: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Tags: python

I am building a python project for the school (YouTube video downloader), but when I run it, it appears this error: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
I have already tried other codes from other people and no one worked, I think is my computer. What can I do?

Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from pytube import YouTube #pip install pytube3

Folder_Name = ""

#file location
def openLocation():
    global Folder_Name
    Folder_Name = filedialog.askdirectory()
    if(len(Folder_Name) > 1):
    locationError.config(text=Folder_Name,fg="green")

else:
    locationError.config(text="Please Choose Folder!!",fg="red")

#donwload video
def DownloadVideo():
    choice = ytdchoices.get()
    url = ytdEntry.get()

if(len(url)>1):
    ytdError.config(text="")
    yt = YouTube(url)

    if(choice == choices[0]):
        select = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True).first()

    elif(choice == choices[1]):
        select = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True,file_extension='mp4').last()

    elif(choice == choices[2]):
        select = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()

    else:
        ytdError.config(text="Paste Link again!!",fg="red")


#download function
select.download(Folder_Name)
ytdError.config(text="Download Completed!!")



root = Tk()
root.title("YTD Downloader")
root.geometry("350x400") #set window
root.columnconfigure(0,weight=1)#set all content in center.

#Ytd Link Label
ytdLabel = Label(root,text="Enter the URL of the Video",font=("jost",15))
ytdLabel.grid()

#Entry Box
ytdEntryVar = StringVar()
ytdEntry = Entry(root,width=50,textvariable=ytdEntryVar)
ytdEntry.grid()

#Error Msg
ytdError = Label(root,text="Error Msg",fg="red",font=("jost",10))
ytdError.grid()

#Asking save file label
saveLabel = Label(root,text="Save the Video File",font=("jost",15,"bold"))
saveLabel.grid()

#btn of save file
saveEntry = Button(root,width=10,bg="red",fg="white",text="Choose Path",command=openLocation)
saveEntry.grid()

#Error Msg location
locationError = Label(root,text="Error Msg of Path",fg="red",font=("jost",10))
locationError.grid()

#Download Quality
ytdQuality = Label(root,text="Select Quality",font=("jost",15))
ytdQuality.grid()

#combobox
choices = ["720p","144p","Only Audio"]
ytdchoices = ttk.Combobox(root,values=choices)
ytdchoices.grid()

#donwload btn
downloadbtn = Button(root,text="Donwload",width=10,bg="red",fg="white",command=DownloadVideo)
downloadbtn.grid()

#developer Label
developerlabel = Label(root,text="Dream Developers",font=("jost",15))
developerlabel.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

And here is the terminal:
[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r71uj.png)

[Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJ4eK.png)

Comment: ERROR 404 means you are using the wrong URL

Comment: Well but, how is that possible? Because I am copying the link directly from youtube

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you should add this URL to question, not comment - so we could check it. Besides server may block some urls if it detect bot/script/spamer/hacker because they don't watch ads that give money to the server.

Comment: aalways put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not comment).

Comment: you have wrong indentations - you should run `if(len(url)>1):` inside `DownloadVideo` but you have it outside function. BTW: you could use `print(url)` to see if you really have good URL.

Comment: maybe YouTube changed some elements on server and now pytube doesn't work and you mya have to wait for newer version.

Comment: I tested code doesn't work with `pytube-10.4.1` but works with the newest `pytube-10.8.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested: code doesn't work with `pytube-10.4.1` but works with the newest `pytube-10.8.3`

It seems `YouTube` changed something on server and it needed changes in `pytube`.